# I'm trying to use regex to specify amount of characters. The curly brackets are not working

Tags: regex, servicenow

```
var validRegExp = /^[0-9]+[-]+[0-9]+$/;
```

This is my script, and what I want is:

```
var validRegExp = /^[0-9]{5}+[-]+[0-9]{2}+$/;
```

But when I put this in it doesn't like it.

I want 5 numbers, followed by a dash, followed by two numbers

Comment: Remove `+`s after `}`s.

Comment: _it doesn't like it_ is not a proper error description. However i guess you want just `/^[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{2}$/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write :

```
[0-9]{5}+
```

It's no correct because you can translate it as a numerical 5 times, 1 or more. As you already write 5 times the + shouldn't be used.

The correct regex would be :

```
/^[0-9]{5}(-)+[0-9]{2}$/;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!